# typeorm: how to use manytoone with just one column of primary key?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Consider the following entities:

```
@Entity()
export class One {
  @ManyToOne(() => Two, two => two.oneSomeString)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  public readonly someString!: string

  @PrimaryColumn()
  public readonly someNumber!: number
}

@Entity()
export class Two {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number

  @OneToMany(() => One, one => one.someString, { cascade: true })
  @Column()
  public readonly oneSomeString!: string
```

I want every record of `Two` to recognize multiple records of `One` by just `someString` and not the entire PK (and therefore cascade delete by just `someString`).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
@Entity()
export class One {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  public readonly someString!: string

  @PrimaryColumn()
  public readonly someNumber!: number

  @ManyToOne(() => Two, two => two.ones)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'someString' })
  public readonly two: Two
}

@Entity()
export class Two {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number

  @Column()
  public readonly oneSomeString!: string

  @OneToMany(() => One, one => one.two, { cascade: true })
  public readonly ones: One[]
```